# HTML Custom Input type for schedule

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm looking for a way to input a 'schedule' for a task from a user of a web app I'm working on, and have it be used on multiple pages in my UI.

I was looking for something that would allow me to configure whether was manually triggered, run monthly/weekly/daily/hourly, etc. and then based on the configured frequency show subfields, like day of month for monthly + time of day, day of week for weekly + time of day, just time of day for daily, etc.

I was thinking I could just use multiple select fields, and use Javascript to hide/show the appropriate subfields when the selected frequency indicated I didn't need them.  However, since I want to use this on multiple pages, I don't want to have to do a copy of a bunch of stuff between pages if there's a better way to do this.

Internally, it'll likely be converted to crontab format and use Spring to do the scheduling, but I don't want to display crontab format in a text box, because of its lack of user friendliness.

Anyone have any suggestions?  I'm using Struts 2 for the UI, and am not using any Javascript library for anything.  Not sure if this is the type of thing something like jQuery would make easy, or what.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not create an include and just use the include everywhere you want the functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I ended up using the Struts 2 component tag and just passing parameters to that to generate the appropriate code with different names.  This worked the best for me since using this I was still able to nest Struts 2 tags and I'm not sure if I would have been able to do that by defining my own taglib.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is an option because it makes event handling consistent across browsers, however, writing a simple function that does it is across all browsers in a concise manner is fairly trivial too, so just for this widget I wouldn't recommend creating a dependency on jQuery.

Oh, and think of the input type as a widget or component with a decent public interface that you can just instantiate and embed in any page that needs it. Take a look at how most web calendaring solutions like Google Calendar achieve it, since they need to account for periodical events too, and still keep it simple for the end users. They have a solution to the UI problem of getting really complex recurring times such as:

- Every 5 years on July 13
- Every 2 months on the second Tuesday
- Weekly on Tuesday, Wednesday
- Every 4 days

in a simple manner for an end user. Here are a few examples:

**Yearly repetition with a custom step size**

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8122/picture1be.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8122/picture1be.png)

**Monthly repetition with a custom step size on a certain day of the month**

[alt text http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/8036/picture2so.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/8036/picture2so.png)

Use a self-contained script file that contains the widget, let's say `ScheduleWidget.js` that you can reference on each page that needs it, or maybe it gets bundled in a minified/packed script, so all pages have access to it.

Keep the interface simple, so with minimal effort it can be inserted into any DOM element.

```
var widget = new ScheduleWidget();
var container = document.getElementById("scheduleContainer");
// getElement() returns the root DOM node of the dynamically constructed widget.
container.appendChild(widget.getElement());
```

When the `ScheduleWidget` object is instantiated, it sets up all event bindings so list selection, changes, etc. trigger a change in the logic/UI as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for an answer to this question too.

I do think Google calendar is a great example of how this can be done well, I think there is still a good opportunity for some kind of JQuery plugin or other javascript library.

For any given web applications it will be rare that a GUI will need to be able to create every entry in crontab. For instance, Google Calendar has an impressive array of scheduling options, but still does not support "every other minute from now on"...

For the web application that I am working with now, anything over "monthly" is too long, and anything under "daily" also does not work I only want to have the following options

```
daily options
 daily
 once every two, three or four days
weekly options
 A set number of times per week (like:once, twice, etc)
 weekly on a schedule (like: Tues, Thurs, and Sat)
monthly options
 A set number of times per month (like: four, five, six)
 monthly on a schedule (like: 1st, 7th, 13th, and 21st)
 monthly on a weekly schedule (like: 1st Tuesday, 2nd Wednesday, Last Friday)
```

But it seems pretty obvious to me that what I want is merely a subset of a larger scheduling frequency system that includes hourly, 'minutely', yearly and yearly+ options

I will be exploring the javascript show/hide options further and will try to remember to extend this answer further when I get those done.